# How can I "prepare request body" section in PHP code

Tags: php

How can I form the "prepare request body" in php for the following rest api request:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: text/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{ \ 
   "item": { \ 
     "Day": "2022-03-01" \ 
   } \ 
 }' 'https://halfiyatlaripublicdata.ibb.gov.tr/api/HalManager/getProductPricebyDay'
```

I have following try but no success:

```
//  prepare request body
    $body = array();  
    $body[] = array( "name" => "Content-Type", "value" => "application/json", "location" => "header", "skipEmpty" => true);
    $body[] = array( "name" => "Accept", "value" => "application/json", "location" => "header", "skipEmpty" => true);
    $body = $dataSource->preparePayload( $body );  
    $jsonBody =  array ( "item" => array(   
        "Day" => RunnerContext::PrepareRest( "2022-03-04", false )
    ) );
```

Comment: You might want to add what library you're using. We have no idea what `RunnerContext::PrepareRest()` does or what object `$dataSource` is or how it works/should work.

Comment: It is part of phprunner

Comment: What is "phprunner"? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71321178/edit) your question and include (and tag) what libraries/tools/framework you're using instead of assuming that everyone automatically will know what those are.